# Use of magically Bound Bowls Pair

Tags: magic

After years of research, MagicBowls create a new product:
The nearly indestructible **Bound Bowls Pair**.

Whatever happens to one is applied to the other as it was one object!
We just don't know how to do with those, or how to market them?

BBP is a simple pair of food bowls, whatever happens to one bowl happens to the other. As if they were one object. 
MagicBowls Tech comes to your house and create your Bound Bowls Pair in 3 minutes.

The principle can't be applied to anything else. Bowls must be less than 20 meters away from the MagicBowls Tech.
Line of sight is not needed but recommended, or closest bowls can be bound by accident.
BBP are nearly indestructible while enchanted. BBP can be enchanted only once.
Disenchanting destroys the BBP. It's only for 2 bowls. If one bowl is push by one centimeter the other will have the same movement.

The physic of Bowls:

For movement, the link between two bowls can be explained by a simple experience. 
Put your hand flat on the desk, lift them up parallel to the table, turn them both 45% to the right. Now if someone moves your left hand, the right will mimic it, the force to move the right one will be produced by magic.
For heat, they are always at the same temperature.
For speed, if one bowl is moving to Jupiter at light speed, the other is at the same speed. Even at relativistic speed they are synced.

Magical taboo and rules that can be relevant:

1. Nothing is indestructible, or create indestructible.
2. Bowls and Cups are known to be magically compatible, But only bowls can be bound. But there is already complex but effective magic to determine if it's a bowl or cup.
3. Please don't destroy time, space, or the universe.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81447/discussion-on-question-by-drag-and-drop-use-of-magically-bound-bowls-pair).

Answer (score 3):

You won't sell your bowls. At least not a pair of raw bowls. You can do much better:

### Binded Bowls Pair Based Quantum Computer

What you got is quantum objects. They are really big, but you can still use them.

Just put them together to build your first quantum computer. Sure, your computer is really big, with very few bytes, but so was [eniac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC).

The goal for you now is to minimize this technology, make them as small as possible to improve your computer, before selling it.